# sometimes lambda.invoke doesn't trigger lambda call

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, lambda

I have a long running download task that is being performed by `download-lambda` function. `download-lambda` function gets executed from other lambda function code, let's call it `calling-other-lambda` function.

**Calling-other-lambda function**

```
      try{

           lambda.invoke({
                FunctionName: `download-lambda`,        //<<<<<----- calling download-lambda function with lambda.invoke
                InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
                Payload: JSON.stringify({
                    path: `api/download`,
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                    body: JSON.stringify(req?.body),
                    httpMethod: "POST"
                }),
            }).promise();

         }catch(e){
               console.log(e);
         }
```

**download-function**

```
   // download - function code written in Nodejs

   // connect to RDS-MYSQL

   // fetch data from MYSQL can take 5-7 miuntes

   // preparing data

   // sending email with prepared data to user
```

`download-function` execution may take long time - 5, 10, 20 mins. It depends on the type of the request.

**Problem:**

Problem is, for some unknown reason, sometimes `Calling-other-lambda function` calls `download-function` and sometimes it doesn't. I **don't want to wait** for response to come back to `Calling-other-lambda function` from **download-function**. It is just fire & forget pattern.

I want to be able to execute `download-function` every time when called from `Calling-other-lambda function`. Event If previous call is being executed, new call must execute (parallelly) successfully.

How can I make sure it calls `download-function` every time ? IF it fails to call `download-function`, how can I capture failure and notify user that call was not successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the `InvocationType` to [`Event`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html#API_Invoke_RequestSyntax) in your `lambda.invoke()` call will make the invocation *asynchronous* (fire and forget).

> Event – Invoke the function **asynchronously**. Send events that fail multiple times to the function's dead-letter queue (if one is configured). The API response only includes a status code.

This means that the `calling-other-lambda` will return immediately after triggering the `download-lambda` function, and it won’t wait for it to finish executing.

I can also make an educated guess that your Lambda function might be timing out after 15 minutes, which is the reason for its occasional 'failure'. Otherwise, it should be invoked consistently.

This should work:

```js
try {
    lambda.invoke({
        FunctionName: `download-lambda`,
        InvocationType: 'Event',
        Payload: JSON.stringify({
            path: `api/download`,
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify(req?.body),
            httpMethod: "POST"
        }),
    }).promise();
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    // Here you can add code to notify the user about the failure
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried with Event and it seemed to be working as of now but problem is it executes always previous request. For example when I call `invoke.lambda` with `id : 1`, it doesn't trigger download-lambda. When I call `invoke.lambda` with `id:2`, it executes code for `id:1`. So basically it is one request behind. I don't know what's wrong. If you can help.

Comment: @micronyks How are you checking that? Using the logs? It's most likely just async invocation, and the requests taking some time. There's no concept as 'being behind' - the payload is sent immediately.

Comment: I can confirm with cloudwatch logs. So when I call it with id:1 and wait for, let's say, 5 mins, It doesn't log anything in cloudwatch ( I waited for 10 mins also). When I call it with id:2 and wait for 5 mins to check logs, it logs all info about id:1. I test with very basic functionality so download-lambda code executes within 5 seconds and sends email (but always for previous request). I know it is strange but it happens. Trust me.

Comment: Note that CloudWatch logs aren't the most reliable way to check invocation - as per [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-cloudwatchlogs.html), **'it may take 5 to 10 minutes for logs to show up after a function invocation.** I would advise waiting for 15 minutes after first invocation to check the logs. Let me know what you have in the logs after `id:1` and waiting 15 min.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I accepted it. However, I really face above problem.

Comment: Even after 15 min?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255273/discussion-between-ermiya-eskandary-and-micronyks).